# Can't boot into Windows 8 after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop about a week ago. Although Ubuntu works fine, I have not been able to boot back into Windows 8 since then. After some digging, I found something called Boot Repair and used it. That didn't help either, but it generated this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5602278/. I'm new to this kind of stuff, so any help will be appreciated. If there's something else you need to see, please tell me. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE 1: So I went into the terminal, typed `sudo update-grub`, rebooted, entered recovery mode, and selected update grub bootloader. I let it do its thing, and when it finished, it told me to press Enter, so I did. Then I chose the reboot option, and it failed. So I shut down and started up again. I chose Windows 8 (loader), and this came up:

[image]

Pressing F8 and Enter both just refresh that image. I had to reboot again.

I then chose Ubuntu in the GRUB menu (the one you use to boot into Ubuntu), and it glitched, so I had to restart. This happened to me 4 times; each time it glitched differently. It finally worked on the 5th time.

UPDATE 2: I have a recovery partition, but everything in it except for the option to open the terminal is disabled. Again, thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your grub and next time when you boot into ubuntu, select recovery mode and upgrade grub bootloader.. And then, reboot.. I think it should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that didn't work. I updated the original post with the details.

Comment: Do u have windows' recovery disk?? Seems some problem with your windows installation

Comment: I do, but for some reason, everything except for an option to start a terminal is grayed out. I can't click on anything else.

Answer (score 0):

For my problem, I had two OS flags on the same partition. For this, I went into Ubuntu and used G Parted to make sure I only had one flag set. This is where you can check to see that you only have one boot flag set. Otherwise, you'll have issues. If this does not apply to you, then ignore this step.

I then went back into the funky Windows shell that is in the advanced options or whatever it is when you can't boot normally in Windows. In that shell, type the following to rebuild the boot:

1) Boot to System Repair Options
2) Click on Command Prompt
3) Type `cd bootBOOTREC /RebuildBCD` and hit [ENTER]

this rebuilds the Boot Configuration Data (BCD) file

Type `BOOTREC /FixBoot` and hit [ENTER]

This writes a new boot sector to the partition

Type `BOOTREC /FixMBR` and hit [ENTER]

this writes a MBR to the system partition and will not overwrite the existing partition

Also, if all else fails, these posts contain similar information and may be useful.

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/59206-63-system-boot-windows-professional

Also, this may be helpful as well...

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/rebuild-bcd-store-windows.htm